# Jasmine: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ag-grid

I have an application that uses ag-grid to display data. This data is just user information like their names and email. I am writing a test for one of my functions in the component class. What my function does is this: It retrives a list of users from a url using the getData service. Then is outputs these users to the ag-grid.  My test is trying to simulate exactly that. Here is the function from my component class:

```
  getUsers() {
    this.userService.getData(url_UserList).subscribe(res=>  
    this.rowData = res;
    this.redrawAgGrid();
   }
```

Now here is my test:

```
 fit('should call getData and return list of users', async(() => {
    const response: Test[] = [];

    spyOn(httpService, 'getData').and.returnValue(of(response));

    dashboardComponent.getUsers();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(dashboardComponent.rowData).toEqual(response);
  }))
```

My test should pass and rowData should equal the response. 
 **on the line: dashboardComponent.getUsers()**  I get the error: **Cannot read property  'Api' of undefined** Thank you.

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: ...which would include the minimal test setup, the minimal component under test, and the actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if anybody happens to come by this question, I solved it. Jasmine was having trouble with AGGrid like I said. To solve this issue, in my test, I added the line: `spyOn(component'redrawAgGrid');` Through research online, the api error was usually due to the method redrawAGrid not being called.